# Splitting of a differential signal

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, differential, phy

Can the Ethernet Tx and Rx signals (Using all 4 pairs; RGMII interface) be split into 2 so as to connect to 2 RJ-45 connectors, but only 1 will be used at a time. In general, can we split any differential signals for 2 outputs?

Edit:

Added a picture for better understanding of my question.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your question? RGMII is the interface to the phy not the cable so probably not relevant. What do you want to achieve  by splitting the pairs?  ‘Any’ differential signals is pretty broad , again, what are you wanting to achieve?

Comment: RGMII is not differential. Please explain. Or do you mean the Ethernet side which is differential? So simply a mux to select a connector to PHY?

Comment: You could, in principle, connect the same signals to two connectors at the same time but what stops cables being plugged into both?

Comment: The PHY supports RGMII interface to MAC. But the actual connection is between the PHY and 2 RJ-45, of which only 1 connector will be operational at a time. So, the Ethernet Tx and Rx (all 4 pair), differential lines, can they be routed to 2 of the connectors (RJ-45)? But at any point of time, only 1 connector will be operational on the system. The other connector will be left open & unused. In this case, can we split the Ethernet Tx and Rx signal (all 4 pairs) into 2? One of each connector? I see that there are other ways to do. But in general, can we split the differential signals into 2?

Comment: You really need to draw a schematic of what you're proposing so we can see precisely what you're proposing. And again, Why do you want to split the pairs? What is the perceived advantage?

Comment: Instead of using any extra components, its better to use a the same diff signal lines right?

Comment: Your diagram is unclear, it simply shows arrows without saying what those arrows represent. Show all 8 conductors, labelled as to which polarity of which pair they belong to.

Comment: Sorry. Those arrows represent the Ethernet Tx and Rx (4 pairs).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, we cannot split **any** differential signal and use it on two outputs.

If we are careful, we can split a differential signal and measure the two lines individually as single ended signals.

A differential digital signal (ethernet, HDMI, SATA) will just plain not work if you connect only one of the pair of conductors to the other end.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, I get we can use any differential signals to use on 2 outputs even if one of the outputs are not connected. Could you explain the reason behind on why it might not work? Because, the impedance matching will be done on both the set of pairs of differential signal right? So, when the impedance is matched, why can't we do as such?

Comment: If you have a differential signal, both outputs must be connected for it to work. It is designed to use both outputs, it is not designed to work with one, common mode, signal swing, noise immunity all need both outputs connected. Impedance matching is done differentially between the two lines that comprise the differential signal. Each differential pair stands alone from every other differential pair.

Comment: @Newbie By splitting, you mean connecting two RJ45 connectors in parallel to single PHY, right? Which does not mean you want to split differential pairs to two connectors, but to just connect differential pairs simultaneously to two connectors?

Comment: @Justme I've added a picture in my question to explain my question better.

Comment: By splitting, you mean connecting two RJ45 connectors in parallel to single PHY, right? - Yes

Comment: Which does not mean you want to split differential pairs to two connectors, but to just connect differential pairs simultaneously to two connectors? - Yes

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't connect RGMII signals to two different RJ-45 connectors, or directly to one at all.

The MII interface (RGMII is a faster, fewer signal variant) is used between the MAC (most often a peripheral in a processor) to the PHY (the physical/electrical interface like Ethernet)  The PHY is often an IC outside of the processor.  The PHY signals (these are differential) are then connected to the Ethernet jack.

The RGMII interface has a set of signals for transmit (Tx[0:3]) and another for receive (Rx[0:3]) each with a separate clock signal (TXC, RXC.)

It wouldn't work to have two PHYs driving the Rx lines at the same time into the MAC.  You might be able to connect the Tx lines to multiple PHYs, but not sure that would be useful, and these signals are generally sensitive to timing impacted by layout.

For a system with two or more Ethernet interfaces, some options are either a processor with a dual MAC (two separate RGMII interfaces with PHYs) or an Ethernet switch chip which has at least three ports - one for the processor and two interfaces for PHYs.)
For example, [KSZ8463](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/KSZ8463) a 3-port 10/100 switch chip.

Comment: The PHY supports RGMII interface to MAC. But the actual connection is between the PHY and 2 RJ-45, of which only 1 connector will be operational at a time. So, the Ethernet Tx and Rx (all 4 pair), differential lines, can they be routed to 2 of the connectors (RJ-45)? But at any point of time, only 1 connector will be operational on the system. The other connector will be left open & unused. In this case, can we split the Ethernet Tx and Rx signal (all 4 pairs) into 2? One of each connector? I see that there are other ways to do. But in general, can we split the differential signals into 2?

Comment: It may be an issue for routing the differential pairs in the PCB. One issue will be that  there would be long "stubs" branching off from each signal to the other connector, which would add capacitance to the route.  Perhaps someone with more expertise in high-speed layout can chime in, but depending on the length of the "Y" tracks to the other jack, it could degrade the signal integrity.  You may get away with it at 10/100 perhaps.

Comment: For the same reason, it is not advisable to try to create a "star" network of any sort of differential signaling network, such as CANBus or RS485 at high data rates.  Impedance matching from the source to load is difficult to control.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to be able to select which of two RJ-45 connectors are connected to an Ethernet PHY. This is a solved problem, analog multiplexer chips that can switch Gigabit Ethernet do exist.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in general, can we split differential signal pairs signals to provide them for 2 outputs? If not, what reasons? What would happen if Tx and Rx signal pairs are provided to two RJ-45 connectors?

Comment: I've added a picture in my question to explain my question better.

Comment: Consider high-speed signals as RF signals and they can't have stubs because signal reflections. It is a very advanced concept which you can look up yourself. In simple terms, Ethernet is not intended to be connected to two parallel connectors simultaneously as it will degrade the signal and will work poorly if at all.

Comment: Oh thank you. So, in my case, I understand that we cannot split the Ethernet differential signals to two RJ 45 connectors